# Flex Mobile Application Label display html text

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, flex-mobile

can someone help me?
How can i display a html text on my Label? I want to display img src if the user set a image like emoticion. This is for a chat on mobile devices.

I don't have anything doing, i just want to know how can i do this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use a Label for that, they are not meant for that type of functionality. Use a TextArea or similar.

Answer (score 0):

in fact, i have the solution, but i need some help with this.

I'll use the richtext and richeditabletext.
When the user select the emoticon, that i'll be replaced with the image, so  but when the user click on button to send a message, this must me the real code. For example:
A Gift
the code is: gift_blue
the image is:

I don't want the php save the code for the image, or you think that i have to do this?
Thanks